# Git, merge several local clones

Tags: git

#### Foreword:

I understand that the solution to this problem is not unique to the question. I am asking this question to establish a concise explanation of the steps needed to ensure a set of clones have all their individual tree-ish/commit-ish references added to a single git repository.

#### Assumptions:

- It is assumed that all git repositories in the question/example have had their working trees committed,
- that repositories are available on the local disk,
- there is full read and write permissions on the files,
- that repositories are all working copies (Nothing cloned with `--mirror`)
- there are at least repositories `~/foo/` (primary) and `~/bar/` to merge.

---

#### Question:

In my infancy learning git, (and more so managing svn checkouts with git, but that's beyond the scope of the question,) I've created several, possibly tens of clones of the same codebase/filestructure.

Some of these clones have small amounts of work done locally to them (and committed).

What would be the easiest way to fetch all `branches`, `dangling tips`, `tags`, and ideally `stashes` from each of these clones into a primary repository?

---

#### Approaches:

- I've considered ways to do this, I have a preminition that the simplest way to do this is to add each non-primary repo as a remote, and fetch all objects to the primary repo. *Does fetch have an option akin to the `--mirror` option of `git clone`?*
- I've considered potentially merging the several .git directories together, though I suspect this to be the *worst* possible way to do this; or at least the most likely to make the git checkout "dirty".

Comment: I would go to the first approach (adding everyone as a remote and fetching from them). It might not be a good idea to try to do more than this automatically, as each repo will contain thinks like branch names that may conflict with other clones. For instance, each one may have it own master pointing to different commits. By using remotes, it will be much easier to solve those conflicts.

Comment: as an FYI - neither stashes nor tag objects have namespaces, so you may have collisions there.  I know you can fake it for tags to get them working, but I have no idea about stashes since I don't use them. You could always convert the stashes into branches beforehand though.